# Parse.com Cloud Code, trying to filter query, but query still contains all objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to add unique objects to my parse database, that is, the `name` property must be different for each object. I try to query for all objects with a given name like so

```
 var query = new Parse.Query(Food);
 query.exists("name", name);  
 query.count({
 success: function(number) {....}
```

However, `query.count` is always the total number of objects (90) stored on the database, even though there should be 0 or 1 objects with a given name stored.

EDIT:

Following one of the answers, I modified the code to this. However, I still see duplicates in the database.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Food);
query.equalTo("name", name);
query.first({
success: function(results) {...}
```

Below is the entire (edited) function

```
Parse.Cloud.define("recordFavorite", function(request, response) {

    var foodList = request.params.foodList; //string array of food names
    var foodListCorrected = new Array();
    var Food = Parse.Object.extend("Food");

    // Wrap your logic in a function
    function process_food(i) {
        // Are we done?
        if (i == foodList.length) {
            //console.log("count is " + foodListCorrected.length);
            Parse.Object.saveAll(foodListCorrected, {
                success: function(foodListCorrected) {},
                error: function(foodListCorrected) {}
            });
            return;
        }

        var name = foodList[i];
        //console.log("before name is " + name);
        var query = new Parse.Query(Food);
        query.equalTo("name", name);

        query.first({
            success: function(results) {
                if(!results){
                    console.log("new");
                    var food = new Food();
                    food.set("name", name);
                    foodListCorrected.push(food);
                    // console.log(foodListCorrected.length);
                } else {
                    //don't create new food
                    console.log("exists");
                }
                process_food(i+1)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });

    }

    // Go! Call the function with the first food.
    process_food(0);

});
```

EDIT:

I've tried an alternate approach to this problem using promises, but the line

```
return Parse.Object.saveAll(foodListCorrected);
```

does not seem to be executing.  I've verified that foodListCorrected is a non-empty array.  Below is the entire code for the function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("recordFavorite", function(request, response) {

  var foodList = request.params.foodList; //string array of food names
  var foodListCorrected = new Array();
  var Food = Parse.Object.extend("Food");

  var query = new Parse.Query(Food);
  query.find().then(function(foods) {
      for (i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
            var j;
            for (j = 0; j < foods.length; j++){
                if (foodList[i] == foods[j])
                  break;
            }
            if (j==foods.length)
                foodListCorrected.push(foodList[i]);
      }
      console.log(foodListCorrected.length);
      return Parse.Object.saveAll(foodListCorrected);
  }).then(function() {
  // Everything is done!

  })

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("recordFavorite", function(request, response) { 
    var foodList = request.params.foodList; //string array of food names
    var saveThese = [];

    var FoodClass = Parse.Object.extend("Food");
    for(var i = 0; i < foodList.length; ++i){
        var food = new FoodClass();
        food.set("name", foodList[i]);
        saveThese.push(food);
    }
    Parse.Object.saveAll(saveThese, {
        success: function(list){
            response.success();
        },
        error: function(error){
            response.error("Failure on saving food");
        }
    });
});    

//If a food already exists in the database, then don't save it
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Food", function(request, response){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Food");
    query.equalTo("name", request.object.get("name"));
    query.count({
        success: function(count){
            if(count > 0)
                response.error("Food already exists");
            else
                response.success();
        },
        error: function(error){
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The first time I ran the code, each iteration outputted 0.  The second time I ran the code (with the same data), there was a combination of 1's and 2's, and a couple of errors.  The third time, just 2's and 1's.

Comment: No new objects were created the second and third run.

Comment: So that means there are multiple rows with the same name. Do you want this? @Mahir

Comment: Why don't you use the object id instead? It's a guaranteed unique row attribute. If that's not possible, what are you trying to accomplish? How are food objects created?

Comment: I'm making a college dining app and I'm trying to store a list of all the foods that are served in the dining halls, which I scrape from the online menus.  However, some of foods appear multiple times on the menus, and I don't want duplicates in the list.

Comment: So wherever you save the food objects, if the count (from the code I provided) is 1, then don't save the new food object.

Comment: right, but the problem is that sometimes the count shows as 0 even when the object should exist in the query

Comment: Where is it that you create the Food objects? Is this the only place they're created?

Comment: Only in this function

Comment: Would you try my new function?

Comment: Now it doesn't save any objects.  Also, I added `var Food = Parse.Object.extend("Food");` to your code

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that the `query` and `saveAll` functions are running asynchronously, so `saveAll` is called before any objects are added to the array.

Comment: Would you try again? This should make it wait until all the queries have been called.

Comment: Still nothing, surprsingly.

Comment: I tried adding `console.log("length is " + foodList.length);` right before the saveALl function, but the line is never called, so I think the while loop doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60482/discussion-between-dehli-and-mahir).

Answer (score 0):

The "exists" condition takes in one argument, the name of a key and sees if it exists for a row. So it will return every row where your "name" column has a value, any value. What you're looking for is something like this:

```
 var query = new Parse.Query(Food);
 query.equalTo("name", name);  
 query.first(...)
```

Comment: I just tried this, but there's still some duplicates.  The first time I ran the code, it added 101 objects with some duplicates. Then I tried running the same code with the same data, and added about 40 more objects to the database. Each object appears either once or twice

Comment: Since I posted the question, I've actually tried a new way of dealing with this situation, but it's not working either. I'm about to update my original question